# Can't deduce f = f₁ from f x = f₁ y?

Tags: haskell, typechecking, gadt, unification

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Foo x y where
  Composition :: Foo b c -> Foo a b -> Foo a c
  FMap :: Functor f => (a->b) -> Foo (f a) (f b)

asFunction :: Foo a b -> a->b
asFunction (FMap m) = fmap m
-- asFunction (Composition (FMap m) (FMap n)) = fmap m . fmap n
asFunction (Composition m n) = asFunction m . asFunction n
```

This works as expected... until you uncomment the second clause of `asFunction`! This is actually just an inlined version of a special case the two other patterns already match, so I'd expect it to be ok. But (`ghc-7.6.2`, or also `ghc-7.4.1`)

```
Could not deduce (f ~ f1)
from the context (b1 ~ f a1, b ~ f b2, Functor f)
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             FMap :: forall (f :: * -> *) a b.
                     Functor f =>
                     (a -> b) -> Foo (f a) (f b),
           in an equation for \`asFunction'
  ...
```

Why does this happen, and why then *not* in the other clauses? What exactly should be done to prevent this trouble in more complicated applications?

Comment: It works in 7.8.2... Something was apparently introduced between 7.6 and 7.8 that fixes this.

Comment: @bheklilr Perhaps it was [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7205) feature reintroduction?

Comment: @Ørjan: that seems to be it. Make that an answer?

Comment: OK, I did so, elaborating it a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be related to a feature *left/right decomposition of coercions* that was temporarily removed from GHC's type inference system in order to support more flexible ("unsaturated") type functions, and then [reintroduced when it was found to have annoying effects like this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7205).